# Patching an Entity with a Foreign Key in Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing a Azure Mobile Service which uses a TableController<>. In this controller i use the default method to patch a entity:

```
public Task<ClassA> PatchClassA(string id, Delta<ClassA> patch)
{
    return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
}
```

So patching a entity works, except for the following scenario:

```
public class ClassA: EntityData
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop2{ get; set; }


    public virtual List<ClassB> BCollection { get; set; } 
}

public class ClassB: EntityData
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop2{ get; set; }


    public virtual ClassC CObject { get; set; } 
}
```

When i try to add a instance of ClassB to ClassA where ClassB contains a reference to a already existing instance of ClassC i get a HTTP 409 Conflict:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DB.ClassC'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'DB.ClassC'.
```

Of course, the controller tries to insert the ClassC object of the new ClassB object.

My question is, how can i attach the already existing ClassC instance to the new ClassB object so EntityFramework does not try to insert the ClassC instance? How can i access those properties in the patch object?

For example: when inserting a new ClassB i can attach the existing Class C instance:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostClassB(ClassB item)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CObject.Id))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("no CObject");
    }

    var c = await db.ClassC.FindAsync(item.CObject.Id);

    if (c == null)
    {
        return new NotFoundResult(Request);
    }

    // Attach existing c
    item.CObject = c;

    ClassB current = await InsertAsync(item);
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
}
```

Comment: How are you inserting the data?  Are you using a Mobile Services client SDK or direct REST calls?  Either way, you probably need to change the type of ClassB.CObject to be an ID rather than an object.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? Last example is working but method UpdateAsync is not? Can you give us the code for UpdateAsync?

Comment: @lindydonna-msft I'm using a simple REST Call. Changing this reference to an ID would be a solution but this would be quite annoying, I'm using a ORM Framework to not deal with ID's. There musst be a way to access those references in the Delta<> object.

Comment: @Enes I want to attach the already existing entity to the ClassB in the "PatchClassA" method like i did in the "PostClassB" method, but i don't know how to access this property in the Delta<> instance (the last paramter of "PatchClassA")

Comment: @SvenLauterbach As you said you are trying to patch ClassA and attach it to existing ClassB but you get an exception for ClassC. I dont think anyone can help without the code snippet for UpdateAsync(id, patch). I'll make an example how to patch object with relationship but not sure if that will fit your case.

Comment: @Enes UpdateAsync is the standard method from the EntityDomainManager, i don't have the source of this method. It's the standard method generated by visual studio when you adding a tablecontroller....